# How do I enable execution process logs in VS 2013/MSTest

Tags: mstest, visual-studio-2013

This is the error message I'm seeing:

> The active Test Run was aborted because the execution process exited unexpectedly. Check the execution process logs for more information. If the logs are not enabled, then enable the logs and try again.

Comment: This can occur if one of your tests has a stack overflow exception.

Comment: I'm have this problem, too. Visual Studio uses VsTest.console.exe rather than MsTest.exe. I haven't figured out to enable logs for that yet. I don't get a message like this when I use MsTest.

Answer (score 3):

You can activate *mstest* logs via *mstest.exe.config* file, see [How to enable MSTest logs](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aseemb/archive/2013/01/25/how-to-enable-mstest-logs.aspx).

I'm not sure what "execution process" means exactly in this case, but *mstest* logging could be really helpful.